# Save State of WebView when fragment containing the webview is replaced

Tags: android, webview, fragment, savestate

I am using webview to create a basic web browser,
Currently I have one activity and multiple fragments :

-- Browser
-- something else
--  Something else

in Browser Fragment I have the webview :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".fragments.BrowserFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/webview_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/button_layout"
                layout="@layout/bottom_btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/web_page_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web_page"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to save the state of the webview on screen rotation , by using

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(mWebView != null){
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

and  calling this OnActivityCreated :

```
 mWebView = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.web_page);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }else{
            mWebView.loadUrl(makeUrl(url));
        }
```

This works fine when screen rotates and activity is recreated.
But when I use navigation drawer and replace fragment in the same container and then try to come back to same fragment . The state of webview is lost.

I get the point that onSaveInstanceState() is not called when there is Fragment transaction. So I tried saving the webView state by calling onSaveInstanceState() from OnPause of the fragment. But in that case I get savedInstanceState as null in OnCreateView so I am not able to restore state.

I need to maintain state of multiple webviews and comeBack to them on click of a list.

I also tried saving webview, when onSave() is called in fragment, in a static HashMap in activity and try to assign it to webview of newFragment. But I get Blank screen in that case.

Could someone give me pointers how I can approach this.

Comment: save the url in the onPause() method, send it to the activity and recover it in the onResume() method in your webview fragment

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i dont want to just restrore the url but i want to restore complete state.including back and forward history , position on page , half filled form if any and so on. I just got it working , I saved the state on OnPause. will post the answer soon.

Comment: @swatisaoji could you post your solution please :) this problem has been bugging me for a while

Comment: @DipoAreoye http://www.lucazanini.eu/en/2013/android/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-of-an-action-bar/ Try the solution here : Basically its just saving the state in an instance variable of the Fragment.